# How to Make a Macro that Remembers the location of the mouse when I start running it

Tags: key, autohotkey, mouse

I am trying to find a program that will preform the following actions in order.

- Press '4'
- Double Click Left Mouse Button
- Press '.' 4 times
- Move mouse to x: 1485 Y: 1000 and left click
- Move mouse to x: 1010 Y: 1350 and left click
- Return the mouse to the original coordinates that it was at when I pressed the key to start the macro repeating

I need to be able to start this macro from any point on the screen. So when I press the key to start the macro, I need it to record the coordinates of the mouse cursor, then one it's completed the script, return to those coordinates. All the programs I have looked into have options only for an absolute position and a relative position, which won't work as I may want to run this macro when the mouse is at X:1000 Y:500 or at X:0 Y: 0, but I need it to click in the two specific absolute coordinate locations from no matter where on the screen the mouse cursor is when it starts. Apparently autohotkey can do this, but I took a look at it and I have zero idea how to write any sort of code for it or make it work, so is there another simpler program that can do this, or can someone explain how to make something like this work in autohotkey?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to incorporate some "[Sleep](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Sleep.htm)" time between actions.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance, Force
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

F1::
    MouseGetPos, X, Y
    Send, 4
    Click, Left 2
    Send, {. 4}
    Click, Left 1485 1000
    Click, Left 1010 1350
    MouseMove,% X,% Y
Return
```